# Template non-type parameter with different types

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Let's assume an input template parameter `T` may or may not have internal variable `bar`. I am trying to write a struct that returns the value of `bar` when we have it, and returns some constant when we don't. Here is my attempt:

```
struct A {
  static constexpr unsgined int bar = 20;
  hasBar = true;
};

struct B {
  hasBar = false;
};

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<T::hasBar, int>::type>
struct getBar {
  static constexpr unsigned int bar = T::bar;
};

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<!T::hasBar, int>::type>
struct getBar {
  static constexpr unsigned int bar = 0;
};

int main() {
  getBar<A>::bar; // Expect 20
  getBar<B>::bar; //Expect 0
}
```

I cannot compile this code with C++14. The compiler complains that: "template non-type parameter has a different type".

Why we have such an error and how can I address it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you @Barry. I modified the code to enhance the completeness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class templates can't be overloaded (like function templates); You can use [specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) instead. e.g.

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct getBar {
  static constexpr unsigned int bar = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct getBar<T, std::enable_if_t<T::hasBar>> {
  static constexpr unsigned int bar = T::bar;
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qGGWoqCsccKPaFX8)

Answer (score 3):

You can detect whether `::bar` exists directly without the need for `hasbar`

something like ...

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
struct A {
  static constexpr unsigned int bar = 20;

};

struct B {

};


template <typename T,typename=void>
struct getBar {
  static constexpr unsigned int bar = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct getBar<T,std::void_t<decltype(T::bar)>> {
  static constexpr unsigned int bar =  T::bar;
};

int main() {
  std::cout << getBar<A>::bar << std::endl; // Expect 20
  std::cout << getBar<B>::bar << std::endl; //Expect 0
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/NwxVUu)

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that doesn't needs `hasBar` but simply detect the presence of `bar` (and also maintain the original type of `bar`, if different from `int`)

```
struct A
 { static constexpr unsigned int bar = 20; };

struct B
 { };

template <typename T>
constexpr auto getBarHelper (int) -> decltype( T::bar )
 { return T::bar; }

template <typename T>
constexpr int getBarHelper (long)
 { return 0; }

template <typename T>
struct getBar
 { static constexpr auto bar { getBarHelper<T>(0) }; };

int main()
 {
   static_assert( 20u == getBar<A>::bar, "!" );
   static_assert(  0  == getBar<B>::bar, "!" );
 }
```